# Redirect all subfolder's to parent folder

Tags: .htaccess

Sorry, I do not understand in htaccess and all, what i do, dont work for me.
Please tell me how to redirect from all these subfolders (with one rule):

```
/about/vacancy/sys-admin/
/about/vacancy/lalala/
/about/vacancy/master/
/about/vacancy/lol/
```

To parent folder:

```
/about/vacancy/
```

What i try:

```
#1
RewriteRule ^about/vacancy/(.*)$ /about/vacancy/ [L,R=301]

#2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about/vacancy/.+$
RewriteRule .* /about/vacancy/ [L]
```

Comment: Show us what you tried at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second variant should work, but the first approach is less complex. You just have to slightly adapt it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?about/vacancy/.+$ /about/vacancy/ [L,R=301]
```

In case you are using a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") and not the real http server's host configuration you need to enable those first. Take a look at the documentation of the `AllowOverride` for that.